# Convert unstructured data in a CSV file into JSON formatted data?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, csv

I have a CSV file with unknown encoding and the data is not structured as XML, as in pic. The requirement is to parse this file and convert the data into JSON format. How to do the same?

I have tried with `csvMapper`, it works only if the data is of XML format. I do not think it works when the model properties are not fixed.

I have tried with java 8 streams, but I was supposed to convert the CSV into structured XML with rows and columns.

This works only for ten rows and columns provided if the file is structured.

```
// Read data
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("Cp1252"))) {
            result = stream.skip(1) // skip headers
                    .map(line -> line.split("")).map(data -> IntStream.range(0, data.length).boxed()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> headers[i], i -> data[i])))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your CSV file?

Comment: Why did you expect the data format in a CSV file to be XML? They are totally different!